# Calculate the probability a die roll + x is greater than another die roll + y

Tags: probability, dice

I'm trying to solve a generalized die rolling problem. I want to calculate the probability a die `A` + constant `x` has a greater value than another die `B` + constant `y`, where x and y are arbitrary numbers between 0 and 20.

I can't quite figure out how to sum the probability of all possible roll combinations where `A+x > B+y`.

Comment: Presumably, $x,y$ are fixed, and not also random. “Arbitrary” is a word with little formal meaning, but in probability, it becomes a muddled word.

Comment: Habe you tried to solve it with a table?

Comment: Yes x and y are fixed values. I need this as a function for a Python script. So I thought there might be a better solution than a table.

Comment: @Abl3t0nnile The table is meant as a starting point. From there you probably can deduce an algorithm.

Comment: You may wish to look at cases, for instance, what if constant $x$ is set greater than $6$ while constant $y$ is set at $0$?  FYI, constants are more often assigned  $a, b, c, k$, for instance, while $x, y$ tend to represent variables.

Comment: @callculus42 Thanks! You're right. I'll have a look at that.